# jQuery JSON Array undefined / not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-8, background-color

As a Javascript novice, I'm having a hard time figuring out the following issue:

I have an external JSON file with a list of colors.

```
[
{"num": "1B2-5","nam": "burntsienna","hex": "EA7E5D","com": "int2"},
{"num": "1B3-5","nam": "cadetblue","hex": "5F9EA0","col": "int1"},
{"num": "1B1-6","nam": "chartreuse","hex": "7FFF00"},
{"num": "1B2-6","nam": "chocolate","hex": "D2691E","com": "int2"}
]
```

At this point in the code, the background-color value of #background will be equal one of the values in the JSON file. I convert the background-color value to hex, remove the '#' character, and find its index number in the JSON array. I then declare variables for the corresponding properties using the index number.

I have shortened the code for the purpose of this example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('_js/json.js', function(colors_list){ 

    var pageColorPre = rgb2hex($('#background').css('background-color'));
    var pageColor = pageColorPre.toUpperCase().substr(1);
    var pageColorIndex = findIndexByKeyValue(colors_list, "hex", pageColor)

    var nameByIndex = colors_list[pageColorIndex].nam
    var numberByIndex = colors_list[pageColorIndex].num
    var comByIndex = colors_list[pageColorIndex].com


function findIndexByKeyValue(obj, key, value){
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i][key] == value) {
        return i;
        }
      }
      return null;
}

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 if (  rgb.search("rgb") == -1 ) {
      return rgb;
      } else {
      rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
      function hex(x) {
           return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
      }
      return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]); 
      }
}
});
});
```

Even though the code works well in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, when the browser reaches this line:

```
  var numberByIndex = colors_list[pageColorIndex].num
```

I get the following errors when debugging:

```
uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'nam' of undefined.
```

The code breaks in IE8 with the following message:

```
'colors_list[...] nam'is null or not an object.
```

I thought perhaps since the "com" and "col" values are sometimes null, not every color has them, that might be an issue. However, I get the same error message even when only declaring a property such as "nam" or "num" which every color has.

Thanks.

Comment: `"com": int2"},` << your missing quotes here. that will completely destroy the rest of your array if that's what you actually have in your file.

Comment: in first line you have error in your JSON - missing open quote - `int2"`

Comment: Try a `console.log(pageColor, pageColorIndex)` for debugging?

Comment: @ryan, jcubic: That's probably not the error, as jQuery would not call the success callback with invalid JSON, and that exception would not be thrown :-)

Comment: My assumption is `pageColorIndex` is returning null

Comment: Check what value you get from `$('#background').css('background-color')` maybe it's different in IE

Comment: I don't believe it's a JSON formatting issue... the missing quote was a typo I made when posting the question... sorry.

Comment: console.log(pageColor, pageColorIndex) returns ReferenceError: pageColor is not defined

Comment: actually... console does return the correct values

Comment: Firstly stick in the semi-colons to denote the end of process lines and sort out your curly brace formatting to get some obvious function beginnings and endings. Secondly, out of interest, did you try using colors_list[pageColorIndex]['num'] instead of the dot notation? I've come across weird scenarios where one works and the other didn't for reasons known only to those we do not speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post this as new answer, as the previous answer was in reference to what seemed to be a typo in the question...

The error you're getting is actually in relation to the line:

```
var nameByIndex = colors_list[pageColorIndex].nam
```

This is why it's not reaching the next line in which you try to get the `NumberByIndex`. (By the way, you should be ending those lines with a semi-colon `;`, to prevent further problems...)

The problem is with the object...

```
colors_list[pageColorIndex]
```

...in that it seems to be showing up as null. Since we "know" that `colors_list` (though it might be worth debugging to check) is a valid array, the problem must be with `pageColorIndex` which is originally returned by `findIndexByKeyValue()`; it could be that `findIndexByKeyValue` is returning null.

It would be worth inserting the lines `console.log(obj[i][key])` and `console.log(value)` above your conditional statement and checking what they look like in the console when you run the code again. Look in particular for unexpected spacing, before or after the hex value. You might find that the `pageColor` variable is not formatted as you expected it to be and therefore not matching with any of the hex values in your array objects and returning null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but I checked it and the console returns the correct values

Answer (score -1):

**Update** - according to jcubic, this doesn't apply to JSON, so I'm retracting this answer.

Not sure if it's your whole problem, but you're not declaring objects right - keys aren't usually strings.

Instead of:

```
{"num": "1B2-5","nam": "burntsienna","hex": "EA7E5D","com": "int2"}
```

You want:

```
{ num: "1B2-5", nam: "burntsienna", hex: "EA7E5D", com: "int2"}
```

Comment: No, if the JSON would have been invalid the reported exception could not have been thrown at all…

Comment: in JSON keys need to be inside quotes, JSON is different then JavaScript Object literal.